# How to solve error with downloading Jupyter Notebook as HTML with toc?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tableofcontents

When I try to download jupyter notebook as HTML with ToC, it gives a

> 500 Internal Server Error: nbconvert failed: toc2

I have tried to reinstall nbextensions, upgrade notebook, and tried to download notebook with the *File>>Download As* method and the command method, all with no luck.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html_toc names.ipynb
```

gives the following error

```
File "C:\Users\Elle\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 429, in load
    raise TemplateNotFound(name)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: toc2
```

**I was able to download as HTML, but unable to do so with ToC. The toc2 folder is in `\miniconda3\share\jupyter\nbextensions`. The toc2.tpl is in `\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_nbextensions\templates`**

I am not sure what steps I should follow to have this work.

Answer (score 11):

After googling, I fixed it by downgrading nbconvert to version 5.6.1

```
conda install "nbconvert=5.6.1"
```

Comment: This version works, however, there is a need to check into why version 6.0 and above of nbconvert fails to export a notebook as HTML with a table of contents.

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge "nbconvert=5.6.1"`

Comment: Unfortunately, nbconvert `5.6.1` does not work anymore wiht the latest jupyter lab, so this either means no `toc2` in html converts or not using recent jupyter lab. :/